# Migrating existing API project to .NET 8 getting error when creating JWT tokens

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I just upgraded an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API to .NET 8 (note everything worked perfectly fine in .NET 6) and I'm getting this error when creating a JWT token:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'IDX10720: Unable to create KeyedHashAlgorithm for algorithm 'HS256', the key size must be greater than: '256' bits, key has '152' bits. (Parameter 'keyBytes')'

Based on what I understand from this error, it looks like there is a new requirement for how long the secret needs to be so I made the secret longer, which works for creating the token but when reading the token I get a whole new error

> System.ArgumentException: 'IDX12723: Unable to decode the payload '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' as Base64Url encoded string.'

Edit: here is the inner exception maybe this can shed some light

> JsonException: IDX11020: The JSON value of type: 'String', could not be converted to 'JsonTokenType.Number'. Reading: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.iat', Position: '52', CurrentDepth: '1', BytesConsumed: '75'.

Is there some breaking changes here for handling JWT tokens?

Here's the code of the private method reading the token

```
private User? _GetIdentity(HttpContext context, string token)
{
     try
     {
         var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
         //var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token);
         var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;//error happens here
         
         var user = new User
         {
             Id = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value,
             UserName = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value,
             Email = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value,
             Role = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Value
         };

         if (tokenS.ValidTo < DateTime.UtcNow)
         {
             throw new Exceptions.UnauthorizedAccessException($"...");
         }

         return user;
     }
     catch(Exceptions.UnauthorizedAccessException e)
     {
        _logger.LogError(e.Message);
         throw;
     }
}
```

Here's the code for the class generating the JWT token:

```
public class JwtService
{
    private const int EXPIRATION_TOKEN_MINUTES = 25;
    private const int EXPIRATION_REFRESH_DAYS = 7;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public JwtService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse CreateToken(IdentityUser user, IEnumerable<string> roles)
    {
        var expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(EXPIRATION_TOKEN_MINUTES);
        var refreshExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(EXPIRATION_REFRESH_DAYS);
        var token = CreateJwtToken(
            CreateClaims(user, roles),
            CreateSigningCredentials(),
            expiration
            );
        var refreshToken = CreateJwtToken(
            CreateRefreshTokenClaims(user.Id),
            CreateSigningCredentials(),
            refreshExpiration
            );

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        return new AuthenticationResponse
        {
            Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
            RefreshToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(refreshToken),
            Expiration = expiration
        };
    }

    private JwtSecurityToken CreateJwtToken(Claim[] claims, SigningCredentials credentials, DateTime expiration) =>
        new JwtSecurityToken(
            _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            claims,
            expires: expiration,
            signingCredentials: credentials
        );

    private Claim[] CreateRefreshTokenClaims(string userId) =>
        new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.Now.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId)
        };

    private Claim[] CreateClaims(IdentityUser user, IEnumerable<string> roles) =>
         new[] {
            //new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),

         }
         .Concat(roles.Select(r => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r)).ToArray())
         .ToArray();

    private SigningCredentials CreateSigningCredentials() =>
        new SigningCredentials(
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Secret"])
            ),
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256
        );

    public ClaimsIdentity CreateClaimsIdentity(string username, string userId, IEnumerable<string> roles)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId)
        };

        claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            claims,
            "Token",
            ClaimTypes.Name,
            ClaimTypes.Role
            );

        return identity;
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            // Set the token validation parameters
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidAudience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                ValidIssuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Secret"])
                )
            };

            // Validate and parse the token
            var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var _);

            return principal;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Token validation failed
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It really sounds like the padding of the secret is not the right size. Note put these two lines in the startup to see the PII `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
IdentityModelEventSource.LogCompleteSecurityArtifact = true;` and remove them before going to production.

Comment: For the first error,check Jwt:Secret in your appsettings.json,ensure the length of Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Secret"])  is greater than 32

Comment: Thank you Ruiki Feng i did that thats what led me to my second error..

Comment: megaMan where exactly should i add these 2 line?

Answer (score 6):

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'IDX10720: Unable to create
> KeyedHashAlgorithm for algorithm 'HS256', the key size must be greater
> than: '256' bits

This error occurs because of breaking change in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens nuget (starting from 6.30.1), an additional check of minimal key size (that depends on the hash algo) was added into [CryptoProviderFactory.cs "CreateKeyedHashAlgorithm" method](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/rel/7.1.2/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/CryptoProviderFactory.cs#L490) and according to the source code there is no way to enable 'backward compatibility mode' unfortunately.

If you have control over your JWTs and they can be easily re-generated this should not be a problem, however it's a big problem if:

- your .NET Core app verifies JWTs generated from 3rd parties - most libs don't check minimal key size an allow JWT signatures generated with 'short' keys.
- your .NET Core app has long-term JWTs (like API tokens used for external integrations) and they already generated with short keys. You simply cannot keep backward compatibility with these JWTs which might be a true blocker.

I've faced the same issue and it was vital to have backward compatibility behavior in my apps. I've checked .NET HMACSHA256/HMACSHA384/HMACSHA512 implementations and found that they didn't change and in fact it is still possible 'short' keys because when key size is not sufficient to fill the buffer it has zeros by default. This means that we can 'extend' short keys with zeros to pass minimal key size check and at the same time have 100% backward compatibility in terms of JWTs generation/verification:

```
SymmetricSecurityKey ExtendKeyLengthIfNeeded(SymmetricSecurityKey key, int minLenInBytes) {
    if (key != null && key.KeySize < (minLenInBytes * 8)) {
        var newKey = new byte[minLenInBytes]; // zeros by default
        key.Key.CopyTo(newKey, 0);
        return new SymmetricSecurityKey(newKey);
    }
    return key;
}
```

To guarantee that 'short' key is extended with zeros automatically it is enough to specify TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeyResolver handler:

```
jwtParams.IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (tokenString, securityToken, identifier, parameters) => {
    string alg = null;
    if (securityToken is JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken)
        alg = jwtSecurityToken.SignatureAlgorithm;
    if (securityToken is Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken jsonWebToken)
        alg = jsonWebToken.Alg;
    if (parameters.IssuerSigningKey is SymmetricSecurityKey symIssKey 
        && alg!=null) {
        // workaround for breaking change in "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 6.30.1+ 
        switch (alg?.ToLowerInvariant()) {
            case "hs256":
                return new[] { ExtendKeyLengthIfNeeded(symIssKey, 32) };
            case "hs512":
                return new[] { ExtendKeyLengthIfNeeded(symIssKey, 64) };
        }
    }
    return new[] { parameters.IssuerSigningKey };
};
```

To generate JWTs with 'short' keys it is enough to use `ExtendKeyLengthIfNeeded` while setting `TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey`.

Comment: This is the one that made me fix the problem after a week of searching for a proper fix due to the incompatible backwards compatibility change for the feature. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem.

The JWT Field Iat should be a number (seconds since 01.01.1970)

When generating your JWT, simply replace:

```
  claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString())),
```

with:

```
 long iat = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
 claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, iat.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @Vitaly post a simpler and more accurate approach is to just create your "SymmetricSecurityKey" with 256 bits which I'm guessing like me you were using a Guid which is only 128 bits.

```
// a guid is 128 bits but the security key for SHA256 needs to be 256 bits
var key = authID.ToByteArray();
var keyDouble = new byte[key.Length * 2];
Array.Copy(key, keyDouble, key.Length);// NOTE: the remainder can be left zero
securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyDouble);
```

Comment: i was doing  new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Secret"])) which i made sure is long enough but i still ended up getting that second error when trying to read it?

Comment: Are you sure your key is 256 bits long? Try my approach as a test. Do: "var authID = Guid.NewGuid()" and then use the logic from above. Also make sure the "SymmetricSecurityKey" instance is being used in all places. There are multiple.